# Tensorflow embedding_lookup gradients registering on CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have something equivalent to a sparse softmax:

```
...
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    indices = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, dimsize])
    self._W = weight_variable([self._num_nodes, input_layer_size])
    self._b = bias_variable([self._num_nodes])
    sampled_W = tf.transpose(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self._W, indices), [0,2,1]) # [batchsize, inputlayersize, dim1size]
    sampled_b = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self._b, indices) # [batchsize, dim1size]
    ...
```

However, when I enable placement logging, I see multiple instances of the gradients being placed on the CPU, e.g.:

```
gradients/.../embedding_lookup_1_grad/Size: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:819] gradients/.../embedding_lookup_1_grad/Size: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
```

This happens no matter the optimizer I choose. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If this is happening on a gpu, is there any advantage to using `embedding_lookup` over `gather`?

Comment: That's a good point. I actually just was trying that myself as well. It doesn't seem like there's any benefit. Problem solved!

Comment: @WesleyTansey I have a similar problem. So, you solved your problem by replacing embedding_lookup with gather? am I right?

Comment: Yep. If you can fit everything on memory on the GPU, you can do it with just a gather. Note that gather_nd does not support GPU though. For an example, see the LocallySmoothedMultiscaleLayer class here: https://github.com/tansey/sdp/blob/master/tfsdp/models.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=False))
```

you should get an error. That's because `embedding_lookup` isn't implemented on the GPU currently.

Comment: what about now?

Comment: @MeadowMuffins I haven't really kept up with TF developments after Pytorch got released, so I can't say.

Comment: @MeadowMuffins no. I believe tf still doesn't have GPU support for `embedding_lookup`. see the similar issue I run into [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644982/tensorflow-distributed-training-high-bandwidth-on-parameter-server)