# Tensorflow distributed training high bandwidth on Parameter Server

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, distributed-system

We trained a DNN model in the distributed mode with the parameter server strategy. The model has an embedding layer and some code like

```
with tf.colocate_with(embeddings):
   tf_output = tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse(embeddings, tf_ids, name=name + '_lookup')
```

This results in the GPU on workers is peak at ~10% (very low) due to network bandwidth saturated. If we comment out `with colocate_with(embeddings)`. GPU on workers bump up to 30+%.

Curious what the possible reason for this. Since embeddings are allocated on PS, the difference seems where the `embedding_lookup` happens(at worker or PS). Here comes the mysterious part. `colocate_with` means both embedding variable and embedding lookup op on PS.